# How to write for reserved bits during SPI communication in Arduino Due?

Tags: arduino

I am interfacing an Arduino device to a Phase Locked Loop chip using SPI, however have become confused about how to write the data I need to input. Note the following latch summaries

[Latch Summaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBSJr.png)

Note how in the reference counter latch, the most significant bit (DB23) is noted as x. The same can be said of DB23 and DB22 in the N Counter Latch.

What does this 'x' mean? Also, if I want to transfer data, how would I do this? What would I put in place of the x?

Comment: x = "don't care" (write) or "unknown" (read). Don't make them random but `0`.

Comment: That's not a programming question, but how to read a datasheet. And Arduino is not C!